# Mass Find/Replace within files having specific filename under command line

Tags: search, replace, grep

I am looking for a quick command to search all `.htaccess` files for a specific IP address and change it to another IP address from the command line

something like

```
grep -rl '255.255.254.254' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/254/253/g'
```

I know the above example is a bad way to do it, just an example (and showing I did some searching to find a solution

```
Search: files with filename .htaccess (within 2 levels deep of current path?)
Find: 255.255.254.254
Replace with: 255.255.253.253
```

or, is this too much to ask of my server and I would be better off replacing them as I find them?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
find . -type f -name '.htaccess' -execdir sed -i 's/255\.255\.254\.254/255.255.253.253/g' {} +
```

How it works:

- `find .`

  Start looking for files in the current directory.
- `-type f`

  Look only for regular files.
- `-name '.htaccess'`

  Look only for files named `.htaccess`.
- `-execdir sed -i 's/255\.255\.254\.254/255.255.253.253/g' {} +`

  For any such files found, run this sed command  on them.

  Because `.` is a wildcard and you likely want to match only literal periods, we escape them: `\.`

  We use `-execdir` rather than the older `-exec` because it is more secure against race conditions.